# How create a grid in which a variable number of squares automatically resize to fit a space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this problem: http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/javascript-and-jquery?ref=lnav.

Basically, I need to create a game in which the user clicks a button, is asked how many squares they want in their grid, and the grid appears and they can draw on the grid by mousing over the squares which changes their color. So far, I figured out everything Except how to automatically resize the squares to take up the full space of the div container they are in (I restricted the shape of the 16x16 grid to a square by placing it in a div with the id container that had a set height and width).
I tried to play around with the css, changing the height and width to 100%. When I do that though, they just appear in a column and not a grid.

If you open this up in jsfiddle, and request a grid of 16 squares per side, you will see what I WANT to have happen. 16 squares per side is the max, and I would like any lower number of squares to fill up that space and stay in a square grid format, not form a column. Im unsure of whether the solution involves CSS or jQuery. Thank you for any help!

Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div id ="button">
  <p>Play the game</p>
</div>
<div id ="container"></div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.squares {
  background-color: #c266ff;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 470px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddcee6;
  border: 2px solid #ddcee6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #19171a;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is the jquery/javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var x = prompt("How many squares do you want on each side of the grid? Pick between 1 and 16.");
    for(var i = 0; i < (x*x); i++) {   
      $("<div class='squares'></div>").appendTo("#container");
    }
    $(".squares").one("mouseover", function() {
      $(this).css("background-color","#6b00b3");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I improved your formatting for you but you should really get in the habit of indenting your code properly. It helps a whole lot when trying to understand your code and debug it. Also, you have a few redundant css rules and a mismatched closing `div`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advise! This is only my second question here, still learning. Ill keep those things in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var x = prompt("How many squares do you want on each side of the grid? Pick between 1 and 16.");
    var s = (100 / x);
    for(var i = 0; i < (x*x); i++) {
      $("<div class='squares' style='width:" + s + "%; height:" + s + "%'></div>").appendTo("#container");
    }
    $(".squares").one("mouseover", function() {
      $(this).css("background-color","#6b00b3");
    });
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

```css
.squares {
  background-color: #c266ff;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 470px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddcee6;
  border: 2px solid #ddcee6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #19171a;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id ="button">
  <p>Play the game</p>
</div>
<div id ="container">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, this was exactly what I needed. One quick question though, can you explain why the width and height are set up like this? width:" + s + "%   Why not just write width:"s"%  ? What are the spaces and + signs doing?

Comment: @J.Mead You need `width:" + s + "%` to get the variable to inject into the string. If just `width:s%` the result would be the char _s_, not the variable value. Did this make sense to you?

Comment: @J.Mead Check this simple fiddle and you'll see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/83Lwk52h/1/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that you can calculate the height and width, and apply it, using jQuery.

```
//Calculate squares height and width
var containerHeight = $('#container').innerHeight();
var containerWidth = $('#container').innerWidth();
var squareMargins = ($('.squares').outerWidth(true) - $('.squares').outerWidth()) * x;  //Margin * x to take margin space into account, otherwise calculation will be off
var squareHeight = (containerHeight - squareMargins) / x;
var squareWidth = (containerWidth - squareMargins) / x;
$('.squares').height(squareHeight);
$('.squares').width(squareWidth);
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ps8wdzb/1/)

Comment: How do we do this in Javascript?